# Standard library issue when cross-compiling

Tags: c++, cmake

I'm trying to cross compile to an ARM with linux from my x86 with a linux.

The issue appears to be that when including some standard library headers like `iostream` or `string`, even if those are included from the path where the cross compiler is, and its standard library, some of the dependencies of those headers seems to be included from my local standard library.

The headers from my local standard library have some x86 specific type definitions which do not exist on ARM hence the compilation fails.

The error shown is:

```
[01m[K/usr/include/bits/floatn.h:87:9:[m[K [01;31m[Kerror: [m[K?[01m[K__float128[m[K? does not name a type; did you mean ?[01m[K__cfloat128[m[K??
   87 | typedef [01;31m[K__float128[m[K _Float128;
      |         [01;31m[K^~~~~~~~~~[m[K
      |         [32m[K__cfloat128[m[K
In file included from [01m[K/opt/fslc-wayland/3.1/sysroots/aarch64-fslc-linux/usr/include/c++/9.3.0/cwchar:44[m[K,
                 from [01m[K/opt/fslc-wayland/3.1/sysroots/aarch64-fslc-linux/usr/include/c++/9.3.0/bits/postypes.h:40[m[K,
                 from [01m[K/opt/fslc-wayland/3.1/sysroots/aarch64-fslc-linux/usr/include/c++/9.3.0/iosfwd:40[m[K,
                 from [01m[K/opt/fslc-wayland/3.1/sysroots/aarch64-fslc-linux/usr/include/c++/9.3.0/ios:38[m[K,
                 from [01m[K/opt/fslc-wayland/3.1/sysroots/aarch64-fslc-linux/usr/include/c++/9.3.0/ostream:38[m[K,
                 from [01m[K/opt/fslc-wayland/3.1/sysroots/aarch64-fslc-linux/usr/include/c++/9.3.0/iostream:39[m[K,
                 from [01m[K/home/lorandpetok/cross_ws/src/rvc_robot/rvc_ui/include/ConsoleMenu.h:5[m[K,
                 from [01m[K/home/lorandpetok/cross_ws/src/rvc_robot/rvc_ui/src/ConsoleMenu.cpp:1[m[K:<
```

Here you can see that I include `iostream`, the includes cascade down to `cwchar` which in turn includes `floatn.h` from my local x86 library.

The compiler used for cross compilation is gcc 9.3.0

My cmake toolchain file used:

```
set(ARTHERO_SYSROOTS "/opt/fslc-wayland/3.1/sysroots")
set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME Linux)
set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR armv8-a)

set(TOOLCHAIN_PREFIX ${ARTHERO_SYSROOTS}/x86_64-fslcsdk-linux/usr/bin/aarch64-fslc-linux/aarch64-fslc-linux-)
set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER ${TOOLCHAIN_PREFIX}gcc)
set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER ${TOOLCHAIN_PREFIX}g++)

set(CMAKE_SYSROOT ${ARTHERO_SYSROOTS}/aarch64-fslc-linux)
set(CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH ${CMAKE_SYSROOT}/usr/lib/cmake ${CMAKE_SYSROOT}/opt/ros/melodic/share)

set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH ${CMAKE_SYSROOT} ${CATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX})
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_PROGRAM NEVER)
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_LIBRARY ONLY)
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_INCLUDE ONLY)
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_PACKAGE ONLY)

set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${CMAKE_SYSROOT}/opt/ros/melodic/share)

set(LD_LIBRARY_PATH ${CMAKE_SYSROOT}/opt/ros/melodic/lib)

set(COMPILER_FLAGS " -march=armv8-a -mtune=cortex-a53")
set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} ${COMPILER_FLAGS}" CACHE STRING "" FORCE)
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} ${COMPILER_FLAGS}" CACHE STRING "" FORCE)

include_directories(/opt/fslc-wayland/3.1/sysroots/aarch64-fslc-linux/opt/ros/melodic/include/)
```

What could make the compiler or cmake to include the header from my local standard library and how should i tell it to look in the correct path?

Comment: Cross-compiling is more than just setting a compiler. See [documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-toolchains.7.html#cross-compiling-for-linux) about how to cross-compile in CMake.

Comment: @Tsyvarev I edited the question to show the whole cmake toolchain file and thanks for the link i'll have a look.

Comment: Have you checked that CMake correctly detects your cross-compiler at configuration stage (when you run `cmake`)? By using `make V=1` for build the project, you could also examine exact compiler invocation. You may check that given invocation doesn't have `-I` options with system include directories (like `/usr/include`).

Comment: @Tsyvarev The cmake configuration finds the correct compilers and they are working, although i see some `-I/usr/include` occurences durring the build, but i have no idea what causes it to be listed. All the libraries which i need are present in the cross compilation rootfs too.

Comment: The first thing you could do is to prepare simple "Hello world" CMake project and try to build it with `V=1` option. Having `-I/use/include` among options to the compiler would mean that **CMake** somehow incorrectly determines your cross-compiler and its properties. Not having `-I/use/include` for the simple project means that this option is emitted by your **original project**. In that case you need to debug your original project and find out the reason of that option. Note that Stack Overflow is not intended for debugging. This is why we prefer a question to contain [mcve].